# Adding Int to DateTime in format DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: c#, winforms, date

I have got maskedTextBox1 in which I got date in format and mask `DD/MM/YYYY` and in textBox2 I got int value.

Now I need to add int number to maskedTextBox1 value and display it in next maskedtextbox2. The int value should be added to days e.g.: `20/09/2013` + 8 = `28/09/2013`

May I ask how it can be done?

I tried this:

```
string date1 = maskedTextBox2.Text;
string nodays = zpocdnu.Text;

maskedTextBox1.Text = date1 + nodays;
```

But as I'm not that long in c# I'm not sure what conversion shouldI choose.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Edit - this is the answer - thanks to Rajesh Subramanian:

```
        private void zpocdnu_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime rs;

        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-IE");

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(this.maskedTextBox2.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", ci, DateTimeStyles.None, out rs) && zpocdnu.TextLength > 0)
        {


            DateTime today = DateTime.Parse(maskedTextBox2.Text);
            DateTime answer = today.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(zpocdnu.Text) - 1);


            maskedTextBox1.Text = answer.ToString();

        }


    }
```

Comment: `DateTime.ToAddDays()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text);
DateTime answer = today.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(zpocdnu.Text));

maskedTextBox2.Text = answer.ToString() ;
```

Comment: Thank so much, May I ask how can I prevent if maskedTextBox2 contains some value? I tried:  maskedTextBox2.TextLength > 0 But as it is mask it already contains 10 characters. Now I need some conditine so the program won't fall. Thanks again

Comment: You can use DateTime.TryParse() instead, it will tell you its a valid date or not

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the `string` to `datetime`, then add the days and then show this in the text box:
example:

```
string date1= "09/10/2013";
string ndays = "5";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
dt.AddDays(int.Parse(ndays));
string result = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution where wrong user input does not throw exceptions would be:

```
    DateTime dt;
    int days = 0;
    bool success = Int32.TryParse(maskedTextBox2.Text, out days);
    success |= DateTime.TryParse(zpocdnu.Text, out dt);
    if (success)
        maskedTextBox2.Text = dt.AddDays(days).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of masked textboxes, the datetimepicker can be configured like a textbox that only accepts atetime values.  since the resulting value is already a datetime value and you're putting it to another datetimepicker no conversion is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`, it will be even better to use [TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) as remarked on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) as :

> Using the ToInt32(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the Int32.Parse(String) method. value is interpreted by using the formatting conventions of the current thread culture.
>   If you prefer not to handle an exception if the conversion fails, you can call the Int32.TryParse method instead. It returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

You will make an extension method as below:

```
 public static class StringExtensions
 {
      public static int ToInt(this string str)
      {
            int n;
            if(Int32.TryParse(str, out n))
               return n;
            else
               return 0;
      }
}
```

After this , you will just use it in Rajesh's answer as below:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text);
DateTime answer = today.AddDays(zpocdnu.Text.ToInt());

maskedTextBox2.Text = answer.ToString() ;
```